# Unittest Abstract Class exception notImplementederror

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have an abstract class that has multiple `@abstractmethod` that raises `NotImplementedError("Need to implement this")`.

How do I set up a test-case using python's builtin `unittest`?

I tried using `@patch.multibyte` but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I dunno what you are trying to achieve by using `@patch.multibyte`, but if your goal is to test that you have to implement abstract methods in your concrete classes it's just a matter of using `assertRaises`.
Let's pretend to have an abstract class `MyAbstractClass` in module `my_api.py`:

```
import abc


class MyAbstractClass(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_1(self):
        pass
```

Then you write the tests in `my_api_tests.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from my_api import MyAbstractClass


class MyConcreteClassWithoutImplementations(MyAbstractClass):
    pass


class MyConcreteClassWithImplementations(MyAbstractClass):
    def method_1(self):
        return 1


class MyAbstractClassTest(TestCase):
    def test_cannot_instantiate_concrete_classes_if_abstract_method_are_not_implemented(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, lambda:  MyConcreteClassWithoutImplementations())

    def test_can_instantiate_concrete_classes_if_abstract_method_are_implemented(self):
        error = None
        try:
            my_object = MyConcreteClassWithImplementations()
            self.assertEqual(my_object.method_1(), 1)
        except TypeError as e:
            error = e
        self.assertIsNone(error)
```

...but you are actually testing Python's API, not your own code, so such tests are not useful... you have to test your own business logic ;)